# Inherit Backup on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, mojave, time

I used Migration Assistant to move files from my old mac to my new mac, and I want to now inherit backups from my old mac. However, when the prompt came up, I accidentally told it not to inherit backups since I thought that it would overwrite my old backups.

So the issue now is that I try the command line prompt

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup *machine_directory*
```

and it asks me for my password and theoretically it works. However, when I open Time Machine, it still says that the first backup was None and the last backup was None. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Comment: sound weird, but have you reboot the machine after inherit as it gets fixed after rebooting too.